# ¿Cómo impedir que Bokeh muestre el gráfico en el notebook y en una página del navegador al mismo tiempo?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, bokeh

Estoy empezando a aprender a utilizar Bokeh. Mi problema es que cuando ejecuto un script, me lo abre en una celda del notebook y abre al mismo tiempo una pestaña nueva en el navegador con el mismo gráfico. Veamos dos ejemplos sencillos para fundamentar la pregunta.

Este script abre una página nueva en el navegador y al mismo tiempo me muestra el gráfico en el notebook.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
x = [0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0]
y = [10**i for i in x]

fig = figure(title = 'Linear scale example',plot_width = 400, plot_height = 400)
fig.line(x, y, line_width = 2)

show(fig)
```

Este otro script, ¿no debería mostrarme el gráfico  solamente en el notebook:?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show

x = [0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0]
y = [10**i for i in x]

fig = figure(title = 'Linear scale example',plot_width = 400, plot_height = 400)
fig.line(x, y, line_width = 2)

output_notebook()
show(fig)
```

¿Cómo puedo conseguir abrir los gráficos solamente en el notebook?. Agradeceré vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tras muchas dificultades para encontrar una respuesta en Internet, he llegado a la siguiente conclusión.

Es posible que hayamos ejecutado `bokeh.io.output_file()` en algún lugar del cuaderno, para guardar gráficos. Sin embargo, si a continuación solo deseamos que el gráfico se abra en el notebook, tenemos que   restablecer su configuración  de la siguiente manera:

```
from bokeh.plotting import reset_output
reset_output ()
from bokeh.io import output_file, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
```

Si posteriormente volvemos a utilizar la opción `output_file`, si queremos    volver a la opción `output_notebook`, tenemos que volver a restablecer su configuración incial.